# php-fpm (pooling) bug. - The timeout specified has expired

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, caching, ubuntu-18.04

I have a server which has been running for several years without any issues.  However in the past month it has gone down about 5 times now.  I think it has something to do with php7.2-fpm as the simple "fix" is to simply reboot it: `systemctl restart php7.2-fpm`

However I'd like to work out why this is happening and if there is a more permanent fix I can do to stop it.

The Apache error log looks like this:

```
[Wed Aug 18 22:07:05.165386 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9835:tid 140657754629888] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 141.101.107.166:28564] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

Comment: I can only express my sympathy, as the exact same thing has happened here, too, after such a php-fpm upgrade, and I've dug up the entire internet, but every single advice was about tuning the defult timeout... Which _should_ have exactly nothing to do with the change. (Also, it's an idle dev server, the only requests are mine, done manually, and they never even take 100ms (no DB either)...).